# Apache FLUME Distributed

Tags: apache, flume

I am just starting with FLUME. Many installation guides mentioned like single node installation of FLUME… Is there a distributed flavor? How do we install that? What are collectors, i saw them in few docs.. Do we need to physically configure flume with different physical nodes for being distributed or FLUME does it internally.
I want to understand how FLUME is distributed….:)

FLUME internally(logically) scale in machine or it scales, distributes over physical machines.
Seems very basic, but i am just fiddling with FLUME and want to understand how FLUME works...

Comment: We are not here to teach you how to use any particular product, and you're asking way too many way too broad questions. YOU need to do your own research.

Comment: Oh, I saw a lot of docs on Flume and got confused. Just wanted to understand how FLUME is distributed? Do we need to install it in such way or FLUME handles that?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24314530/how-is-flume-distributed